# Can't get dataTables to load table with data from json

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

I use an ajax call to retrieve the JSON information from my server:

```
console.log('GOT IT');
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$('#search-form').submit(function(event) {

  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* get the action attribute from the <form action=''> element */
  var form = $(this),
    url = form.attr('action');


  var data = $('form#search-form').serialize()

  /* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
  var posting = $.post(url, data, datype = 'json');

  /* Alerts the results */
  posting.done(function(data) {
    $('#results-table').dataTable({
      ajax: data
    });
  });
});
```

The data itself is a JSON string return from my server in this format:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "result":[{"salutationtype":"Ms.","firstname":"Jennifer","contact_no":"CON1","phone":"","lastname":"Gale"
}
```

I thought I might have to change the `dataSrc` to 'result' but that didn't work. I also attempted to parse the JSON with `$.jsonParse()` and `JSON.parse()` and feed it to `dataTables` as an object instead of a JSON string but neither worked.

Comment: you get response in `data` var?

Comment: try to change data with data.result

Comment: try this one . `$('#results-table').dataTable({
                aaData: data
            });`

Comment: I keep getting:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined
"

Comment: @chiragsatapara Yes if  i just console log the data variable i get a simple string in JSON format.

Comment: Have you managed to fix this?

Comment: @MJK No I eventually moved on to bootstrap-table and it's been working well for me with that library.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution. This is just an example.

```
$('#results-table').dataTable({
                        "bFilter": false,
                        "bRetrieve": false,
                        "bSortClasses": false,
                        "bLengthChange": true,
                        "bPaginate": true,
                        "bAutoWidth": true,
                        "aaSorting": [],
                        "aaData": data,
                        pagingType: "full_numbers", 
                        scrollCollapse: false,
                        "sScrollX": true,
                        "autoWidth": true,
                        bAutoWidth: false,
                        responsive: true,
                        stateSave: true,
                        sDom: 'R<"data-table-wrapper"rt><"bottomside"ilp>',
                        "drawCallback": function(settings) {
                        },
                        "aoColumns": [
                            {
                                "sTitle": '<input type="checkbox" class="radio_select hathi">',
                                "mData": null,
                                "bSortable": false,
                                "render": function(obj) {
                                    return '<input name="outcomes_chk" id="checkbox_class" type="checkbox" value="' + obj.id + '" class="radio_select madaniyu ">'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "sTitle": "Name",
                                "mData": null,
                                "render": function(obj) {
                                    return '<input type="text" data-name="name[]" class="required  form-control input-sm font-body-size readonly transparent edit no-border" value="' + obj.name + '" >'
                                }

                            }
                        ]
                    });
```

In `aoColumns` put your columns.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you change your following line

```
var data = $('form#search-form').serialize()
```

to

```
var formdata = $('form#search-form').serialize();
/* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
var posting = $.post(url, formdata, datype = 'json');
```

You variable name is data and your param name is also data, and there is a **missing semicolon** in the same line;